# How to highlight a `enumerate` environment in latex?

Tags: color, highlighting, soul, parbox, trackchanges

This is a continuation of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436888/how-to-highlight-some-inline-text-using-parbox).

The following code works very well to highlight a paragraphs(and inline texts too).

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hl}[1]{%
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\linewidth
    \noindent
    \colorbox{pink}{%
        \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{#1}%
    }%
    \else
    \colorbox{pink}{#1}%
    \fi}%Highlighter.
\makeatother
```

But when we use for  `enumerate` environment this gives the following error.

> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. }

As [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik) mentioned in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik) `\trivlist` does not allow paragraph breaks and so I am curious to know how to hack this behaviour and give a global solution, even if I highlight over the pages irrespective of environments(eg. `theorem`) I use(like Microsoft Word, Libre office writer..etc).

### How to hack the `enumeration` to highlight the enumerated list?

---

### Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hl}[1]{%
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\linewidth
    \noindent
    \colorbox{pink}{%
        \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{#1}%
    }%
    \else
    \colorbox{pink}{#1}%
    \fi}%Highlighter.
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\hl{\lipsum[2]}

\lipsum[1]

Some inline \hl{ text} need to be highlighted. 

\hl{
\begin{enumerate}
    \item  This enumeration gives error
\end{enumerate}
}



\end{document}
```

---

Comment: obviously you are allowed paragraphs in lists so I'm not sure i understand your comment abut trivlist. The problem is `\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\linewidth`  as you can not have a vertical constrict in an `\hbox` I think you can simply delete that test,

Comment: If I delete the test, for the inline text it will use the `parbox` which gives a weird behavior.

Comment: sure but why complicate the test you can just use `\colorbox{..}{test}` for the inline case, almost all tex commands use different forms for h and v mode, `\mbox` for hmode and `\parbox` for v mode, why make complcated tests rather than have a vhl wrapping colorbox{parbox and a hhl wrapping colorbox

Comment: I think I did not get u properly. What I understood from your comment is that I should make two different commands for `h` and `v` modes. Is that correct??

Comment: That's what I  would do. It is possible to make the test a bit more robust but it's always going to be the most complicated and fragile  part of the code for what is basically the cosmetic feature of avoiding having two commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not nest `enumerate` in  a `shaded*` environment? It will have the advantage to break across pages. Here's a code with the `framed`and `enumitem` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hl}[1]{%
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\linewidth
    \noindent
    \colorbox{pink}{%
        \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{#1}%
    }%
    \else
    \colorbox{pink}{#1}%
    \fi}%Highlighter.
\makeatother
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\hl{\lipsum[2]}

\lipsum[1]

Some inline \hl{ text} need to be highlighted.

\colorlet{shadecolor}{pink}
\begin{shaded*}
\begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt, before=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\topsep+\partopsep+1.5ex}, after=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\topsep+\partopsep+1.5ex}]
    \item This enumeration gives no error
    \item This enumeration gives no error
\end{enumerate}
\end{shaded*}
 Some normal text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi friend Bernard I wanted to inform you that I quoted you in my reply. Thanks and good work. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436663/graphic-tree-like-symbols-in-text

Comment: Oh! yes. That's a good solution.

Comment: Do you think this is a good idea? After the strong contrast with a user, I think that many have ignored me. is a feeling.

Comment: For me it's fine. I had thought of using this symbol, but not of scaling it slightly as you did, so I finally chose to mix two larger symbols.

Comment: Yeah...I think this is a good solution after your explanation on why there should be two `\newcommand`s rather than checking the length. I just have once question: Why the `*` in `\begin{shaded*} ...`?

Comment: @David: The `framed` package defines two variants of the environment:  `shaded`, for which the contents has its normal width, between the margins, hence the shading overflows into margins (by `\fboxsep`), and `shaded*`, for which it is the shading which is `\textwidth` wide, hence the contents has à slightly smaller width (equal to `\textwidth-2\fboxsep`).