# How can I highlight text in the middle of sentences

Tags: highlighting, code

I want to be able to present short code in the middle of a sentence. How can I highlight text in the middle of sentences in Latex so it they appear as code. Consider this example

> For this purpose we use the `optim()` function.

I have highlighted "optim()". How can I do this exact thing in latex document?

Comment: The `listings` package has `\lstinline`; `minted` has `\mintinline`. For very short stuff you could in theory also use `\texttt` as long as the code does not contain characters special for LaTeX. Do you also want the grey background or is it enough to change the font?

Comment: Those are good suggestions, thanks! It it possible to highlight though? Ideally I will make a line look exactly like the example.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120966/highlight-verb-in-inline-text or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436888/how-to-highlight-some-inline-text-using-parbox

Comment: Also related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357227/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28179/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94965/35864

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "highlight". E.g., a special font, a change in font size, a special foreground color, a special background color (and, if so, which color -- does it have to be grey?), or something else?